# DynamoDbContext warm up in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, .net-4.7.2

I have an issue in dynamo where during initial call the dynamoDb query is slow. I have found out that dynamoDbCOntext caches a lot of stuff. One of the are table descriptions obtained by GetTargetTable() method. Are there other tricks to warm up the context?

I tried calling GetTargetTable to preheat the context before other calls. For example, SaveItemAsync still seem to have a lot of overhead based on SignalFx logs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any sort to tracing to understand where the time is spent? Not only do you have client initialization and its caching, but you also have caching on the DynamoDB side, this can be things like authorization, authentication as well as table metadata.

To keep DynamoDB's internal cache warm, you would need to send dummy dataplane requests, such as GetItem requests. You can do so periodically, issuing GetItem to randomly generated partition keys. This would keep the various metadata cached on DynamoDB which would ensure your initial requests are quick.

Other things you should consider:

- Make sure you set TCP Keep Alive to True
- If you make requests from Lambda, ensure you create the client outside of the request handler
- Make sure you re-use your client and don't create a new one for each method invocation.

Comment: At the moment I am interested only in Client initialization. Based on this https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/173 I understand the need to make Query and GetTargetTable calls on start up. Are you saying this also applies to other operations like SaveItemAsync, Fetch? Would you happen to know how often I would need to "rewarm" the dynamo client?

Comment: DescribeTable is almost always a fast API call. Your timing is not a client initialization problem, but more related to connection start up and table metadata cache being stale. I would use tracing software to understand where you need to improve.

Comment: That's what I am doing at the moment. I could observe whatever it was that the first call on given backend instance is 10x-100x slower. Would you have an idea where is the behaviuor of this class documented?

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Have you ruled out that the 10-100X time taken simply for class initialization, or are you also taking full network connectivity as part of your evaluation?

Comment: Even the network connectivity, as this seems to also cause issues